# fscanf() in C - need help reading a file using pointer notation

Tags: c

Spent an hour or two trying to debug this, but cannot figure out why it won't read my file correctly.

```
FILE *input;
int numAccounts = 7;
char **accountNames = malloc(sizeof(char)*numAccounts*10);
int *accountNumbers = malloc(sizeof(int)*numAccounts);
float *accountValues = malloc(sizeof(float)*numAccounts);
char *fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
input=fopen("input.txt","r");
int i;

for(i=0;i<numAccounts;i++) {
    fscanf(input,"%s%d%f",*(accountNames+i),accountNumbers+i,accountValues+i);
    printf("\n%s %d %f", *(accountNames+i), *(accountNumbers+i), *(accountValues+i));
}
fclose(input);
return 0;
```

And here is input.txt

```
Brown 1435 234.55
Dunn 2091 2011.75
Smith 8766 945.05
Stone 4530 0.0
Becker 9073 6235.75
Rich  1003 -42.00
Doe 6739 3655.80
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with non-dynamic allocation,

```
int main()
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    int numAccounts = 7;

    char accountNames[20] = "";
    int accountNumbers = 0;
    float accountValues = 0;

    input=fopen("input.txt","r");
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<numAccounts;i++) 
    {
        fscanf(input,"%s %d %f",accountNames,&accountNumbers,&accountValues);
        printf("\n%s %d %f\n", accountNames, accountNumbers, accountValues);
    }
    fclose(input);
    return 0; 
}
```

---

If you *must* do dynamic allocation, then this pointer-to-pointer to char allocation is incorrect:
`char **accountNames = malloc(sizeof(char)*numAccounts*10);`

You'd need to allocate `numAccounts` of `char *` first, then for each `char *`, allocate 10 char. That can be done as follows:

```
    char **accountNames = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numAccounts);    // allocate numAccounts of char *
    int i;
    for( i=0; i < numAccounts; i++ )
    {
        *(accountNames + i) = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);            // allocate 10 of char
    }
```

So this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    int numAccounts = 7;

    char **accountNames = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numAccounts);    // allocate numAccounts of char *
    int i;
    for( i=0; i < numAccounts; i++ )
    {
        *(accountNames + i) = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);            // allocate 10 of char
    }
    int *accountNumbers = malloc(sizeof(int)*numAccounts);
    float *accountValues = malloc(sizeof(float)*numAccounts);

    input=fopen("input.txt","r");
    for(i=0; i<numAccounts; i++)
    {
        fscanf(input,"%s%d%f",*(accountNames+i), accountNumbers+i, accountValues+i);
        printf("\n%s %d %f", *(accountNames+i), *(accountNumbers+i), *(accountValues+i));
    }
    fclose(input);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have to use dynamic allocation for this assignment. That double asterisk threw me off from the beginning, but your explanation clears it up. It will be interesting to see how my classmates figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

If the account values are currency. You may want to save them as ints and divide by the lowest unity of that currency.

So instead of saving `float accountValue = 23.25` as `23.25`, save it as `2335` (23.25 * 100).

Then when you read it divide by 100 to get that value back.

```
float accountValueDollars;
int accountValueInCents;

fscanf(..., &accountValueInCents);
accountValueDollars = accountValueInCents / 100;
```

Also, you may want to consider saving in binary format, this way you don't have to worry about parsing the text.

```
typedef struct _account_t{
  char name[50];
  int  account_number;
  double amount; 
} account_t;

int how_many = 0;
account_t * accounts = NULL;

// error checking skipped
fread(&how_many, 1, sizeof(int), input);

accounts = (account_t*)malloc(sizeof(account_t) * how_many);

for(int i = 0; i < how_many; i++){
  fread(&accounts[i], 1, sizeof(account_t), input);
  // print here or whatever
}

fclose(input);
```

NOTE: Untested code.

Comment: This is a small part of an assignment actually, so we have to use fscanf and my variables/pointers can't really change.

Comment: That's why I said save is as int. Otherwise you'll have to eat the space out to get to the float. It's nasty shit